# How to ignore case and number types in Liquibase diff?

Tags: java, integration-testing, h2, liquibase

I am working on a project to get everyone in the company to start using Liquibase to manage our databases, so that we don't have random snippets of SQL flying around. This is especially important as we will be working with clients that use a number of different databases.

There has been some resistance to adopting the new approach, so I want to set up an automated test that spins up an in-memory database, creates it from the changelog, and then compares this database to our DEV and UAT databases, failing if they are different (as this would mean someone has gone in and manually added/removed/changed a table or column).

However, I created an oracle schema using my changelog, then I spin up H2 using the same changelog, and in my diff I get entries like this:

```
defaultValue changed from 'null' to 'NULL'
type changed from 'NUMBER(19, 2)' to 'DECIMAL(19, 2)'
type changed from 'DATE(7)' to 'DATE(8)'
```

Which makes my test fail every time, making it pointless. Is there a way to get liquibase diff to ignore case, and to realise that number and decimal are the same? (or if they are not the same, why does it create it one way in oracle and a different way in H2?)

I could build my own map of 'ignore values' and 'ignore types' but this seems a bit like reinventing the wheel, and I would assume there is some existing solution for this. Or if it would help I am happy to move away from H2 and use Derby or something instead.

Appreciate any help!

PS I am using Liquibase 3.2.2

PPS I am creating my H2 Database in Oracle mode:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:end2end;MODE=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
```

Comment: hsqldb "oracle mode" is designed to understand Oracle syntax queries, but not designed to appear exactly like an oracle dabase when you're introspecting it... In short the diff might be unavoidable, and i don't think liquibase can be told to overlook it (you could perhaps write a small program to parse the output of the diff and decide by yourself if there are legit  diffs)

Answer (score 0):

Comparing data types across data types is difficult because even "equivalent" data types can have differences that some people care about and some don't.

Improving cross-database type comparisons will be a part of Liquibase 4.0 but for now your only real option is to write a custom Liquibase extension that would handle the cases you run into. The general Liquibase extension documentation is at http://liquibase.org/extensions but what you need in particular is to subclass liquibase.diff.compare.core.ColumnComparator and override the findDifferences() method to remove found differences on "type" that are not actually differences as far as you are concerned.

For the case issue you are seeing with null, that may be fixed in the upcoming 3.3.0. I'm not able to reproduce it on the current codebase, but if you wanted to try a snapshot build from https://liquibase.jira.com/builds/browse/CORE-LB let me know if you still see the issue.